# How to split Bezier Curves?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'd like to split bezier curves at any point so that I get two separate curve objects (not just separated in edit mode), preferably while duplicating the split point as new ends so that I don't have to rebuild another end point to make the curves' ends match spatially.

I already tried splitting curves using "split" from the context menu. First of all, it seems like I can't just split a curve at any selected point but I have to select every point up until the one where I want it to split, which I find quite tedious (is this the only way it works?). And then that curve is only split in edit mode - is there a way to split it off as an entirely separate curve object?

Comment: You can CTRL select the first and the last wanted vertices to select all the vertices invetween. Then split, and search for "Separate" or shortcut "P". But I don't think you can split at a single vertex and separate the two parts